# Can't find 'x' or 'y' when trying to recreate cor() function

Tags: r, function

When attempting to recreate the base cor() function I get the following error:

"Error in cor(dataset$variable1, dataset$variable2, use = "complete.obs") : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'variable2'."

Here's my custom function:

```
correlation_recreation <- function(dataset, variable1, variable2) {
cor(dataset$variable1, dataset$variable2, use = "complete.obs")
}
```

Here's how I'm calling it:

```
correlation_recreation(south_eastern_data, Price, Rooms)
```

Here's the dataset:
[Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/anthonypino/melbourne-housing-market)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
correlation_recreation <- function(dataset, variable1, variable2) {
cor(dataset[,variable1], dataset[,variable2], use = "complete.obs")
}
```

The problem with your code is you can't use a variable when subsetting using `$`. The text after `$` is treated as if its a quoted character string. BUT, you *can* use a variable when subsetting with `[]` (that's why if you're trying to use the actual column name inside the brackets, you have to quote it).

Comment: (haven't actually tested it with your data, coz I ain't gonna download no dateset. In the future, please provide a reproducible minimal dataset using `dput`)

Comment: Thank you! I will create a minimal reproducible data set in the future.

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Please upvote and accept the answer! see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers